# How to deserialize JSON objects with variable amount of strings?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Below I have a JSON that details an array of objects, each of which have a `values` property.

This `values` property is also an object, but each `values` object may contain any number of strings:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "xxxx",
            "values": {
                "one": "xxxx",
                "two": false
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "xxyy",
            "values": {
                "three": "xxyy",
                "four": 1.25,
                "five": "xxyy"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "xxyy",
            "values": {
                "six": "xxyy",
                "seven": "xxyyy",
                "eight": "xxyy",
                "nine": 1234,
                "ten": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way I can go about deserializing this JSON object so that I'm able to populate a `values` object, regardless of the number of properties this `values` object has?

I'm using `C#` and `Newtonsoft.Json` to deserialize this.

Comment: which language are you using to deserialise? Is the language strongly-typed, or not? Does it (like C#, which has for example `dynamic`, or Newtonsoft's `JObject`) have some types which could be used to work around the usual strong typing style?

Comment: FWIW that doesn't seem like a great structure for the "values" item...it would be better as an array, if the number of items is uncertain, and especially since they appear to be numbered. Do you have control over the creation of the JSON?

Comment: Sorry about that. I included a language tag in my question.

Comment: And I do not have control over the creation of the JSON. I'm only consuming it.

Comment: I see you tagged C#....so see my original comment for the ways in which people can commonly deal with this kind of thing.

Comment: O.S. If you don't have control over the JSON, do you potentially have any influence or possibility to request changes from those who created it, in order to alter it to a more sensible structure?

Comment: I do. I was just wondering if there were ways to deserialize it how it currently is set up.

Comment: there are, as I mentioned (or you could potentially use a dictionary)...but IMO it's clunky compared to getting it delivered as an array, which it looks like would probably be a lot more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

The below two objects can be used to deserialize the JSON properly:

```
public class AllData
{
    public Item[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }
}
```

And then the following lines can be used to actually do the deserialization:

```
string json = /*json*/;
AllData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllData>(json);
```